# transient noise plot in virtuoso

Tags: noise, simulation, transient, sram, cadence

I was simulating a transient test on an SRAM cell, added a transient noise of 1-30MHZ frequency with 100 multiple simulations and calculated a VQ-QB graph(dots).

I want to be able to only plot the noise graph itself. Can anyone help me with that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Solved by setting all power supplies signals to 0 and running the simulation again- graph of Q and QB displays only the effect of the noise